# Save / Discard Input Selection for all Input Types

Tags: jquery

I am trying to re-create the `save / discard` changes UX for not only text, but for `button` selections as well as `radio` and `checkbox` choices.

I understand how to save the `data-input val();` for text, but how would I apply the same logic to radio and checkbox inputs, as well as buttons that are given an active class (in this case `addClass("focus")`).

The intended behavior is to allow the user to click the `edit` button to make changes, and only if the `save` button is clicked will the code keep the changes else if the `cancel` button is clicked, void all changes and return the original values before the change was made.

```js
// Restricts input for each element in the set of matched elements to the given inputFilter.
(function($) {
  $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on(
      "input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop",
      function() {
        if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
          this.oldValue = this.value;
          this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
          this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
        } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
          this.value = this.oldValue;
          this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
        }
      }
    );
  };
})(jQuery);

$(".input--item").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value);
});
$(".post__item").on("click", ".btn--cancel", function() {
  var parentItemDiv = $(this).closest(".post__item");
  var editBtnObj = parentItemDiv.find('[name="toggle"]');
  var idInput = $(editBtnObj).data("input");
  // clearing unsaved inputs
  parentItemDiv.find("." + idInput).each(function() {
    var oldInputValue = "";
    if (
      $(this).data("old_value") != null &&
      $(this).data("old_value") != ""
    ) {
      oldInputValue = $(this).data("old_value");
    }
    $(this).val(oldInputValue);
  });
  // unchecking edit button & triggering it's on change event which takes further actions like: (a) adding hidden state to "cancel" button etc.
  editBtnObj.prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
});
$(".edit :input").attr("disabled", true);
$('[name="toggle"]').on("change", function() {
  var cancel = $(this)
    .closest(".post__item")
    .find(".btn--cancel")
    .toggleClass("hidden");
  var edit = $(this)
    .closest(".post__item")
    .find(".btn--edit");
  var item = $(this).closest(".post__item");
  var icon = $(this).next("svg");
  var idInput = $(this).data("input");
  var inputEle = $("." + idInput);
  var toggleInput = $(this);
  inputEle.each(function() {
    var inputEleValue = "";
    if ($(this).val() != null && $(this).val() != "") {
      inputEleValue = $(this).val();
    }
    $(this).data("old_value", inputEleValue);
    if (toggleInput.is(":checked")) {
      inputEle.addClass("active");
      cancel.removeClass("hidden");
      edit.addClass("active");
      icon.addClass("fa-save").removeClass("fa-pencil");
      $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      inputEle.removeClass("active");
      cancel.addClass("hidden");
      edit.removeClass("active");
      icon.addClass("fa-pencil").removeClass("fa-save");
      $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("focus");
});
```

```css
.post__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: start
}

.btn__wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 12px;
  color: white;
}

.btn--edit {
  background: orange;
}

.btn--edit.active {
  background: #58d25e;
}

.btn--edit input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.btn--cancel {
  background: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.edit {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
}

.edit input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: red;
}

.edit input.active {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
}

.input--item,
.input--span {
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.input--item {
  border: none;
  min-width: 10px;
}

.input--span {
  display: none;
  white-space: pre;
}

.button.focus {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post__item">
  <div class="btn__wrap">
    <label class="btn btn--edit" for="edit">
  <input id="edit" data-input="update" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </label>
    <a class="btn btn--cancel hidden" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <span class="input--span"></span>
      <input class="update input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="312" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <span class="input--span"></span>
      <input class="update input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="55" />
    </div>
    <div class="subwrap">
      Option:
      <div class="edit">
        <input class="update input--item option" type="radio" name="radio" />
        <input class="update input--item option" type="radio" name="radio" />
        <input class="update input--item option" type="radio" name="radio" checked/>
      </div>
      Button:
      <div class="edit">
        <button class="update button" />Button 1</button>
        <button class="update button focus" />Button 2</button>
        <button class="update button" />Button 3</button>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="post__item">
        <div class="btn__wrap">
          <label class="btn btn--edit" for="edit1">
  <input id="edit1" data-input="update1" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </label>
          <a class="btn btn--cancel hidden" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
          Cost:
          <div class="edit">
            <span class="input--span"></span>
            <input class="update1 input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="40" maxlength="3" />
          </div>
          Price:
          <div class="edit">
            <span class="input--span"></span>
            <input class="update1 input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="79" maxlength="4" />
          </div>
          Option:
          <div class="edit">
            <input class="update1 input--item option" type="checkbox" name="radio1" />
            <input class="update1 input--item option" type="checkbox" name="radio1" checked/>
            <input class="update1 input--item option" type="checkbox" name="radio1" checked/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Note that you should be using `prop("disabled", true|false)` rather than `attr()` See [Attributes vs Properties in the jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#svg-support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made few changes to your code to make little bit more readable and easier to maintain. As a general rule when you are trying to change multiple children its better to change the parent element through jQuery and reflect the change using CSS.

See this code:

```js
function changeInput(inputElements, update = true) {
  // first get all input values and add to data
  inputElements.each(function(i, el) {
    const inputEl = jQuery(el);
    const type = jQuery(el).attr('type');
    const currentValue = inputEl.data("data-value");
    let newValue = '';

    switch (type) {
      case "radio":
      case "checkbox":
        newValue = update ? inputEl.is(":checked") : currentValue;

        if (!update)
          inputEl.prop('checked', newValue);
        break;
      case "text":
        newValue = update ? inputEl.val() : currentValue;

        if (!update)
          inputEl.val(newValue);
        break;
      default:
        // Assuming its button element
        newValue = update ? inputEl.hasClass("focus") : currentValue;

        if (!update)
          // Restore btn focus status if cancelled
          inputEl.toggleClass("focus", newValue);
        break;
    }

    inputEl.data("data-value", newValue);
  });
}

$(".post__item").each(function(i, e) {
  let _this = jQuery(e);
  let parent = _this;
  let inputElements = _this.find(':input');
  let editBtn = _this.find('.btn--edit');
  let saveBtn = _this.find('.btn--save');
  let cancelBtn = _this.find('.btn--cancel');
 
 // disable on load
 inputElements.prop("disabled", true);
 
 // save current data
  changeInput(inputElements);

  // Add click to btns
  editBtn.on("click", function() {
    _this.attr("data-mode", 'edit');

    inputElements.prop("disabled", false).addClass("active");
  });

  saveBtn.on("click", function() {
    _this.attr("data-mode", 'none');

    changeInput(inputElements);
    inputElements.prop("disabled", true).removeClass("active");
  });

  cancelBtn.on("click", function() {
    _this.attr("data-mode", 'none');

    changeInput(inputElements, false);
    inputElements.prop("disabled", true).removeClass("active");
  });
});


$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("focus");
});
```

```css
.post__item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.post__item[data-mode='none'] .btn--cancel,
.post__item[data-mode='none'] .btn--save {
    display: none;
}

.post__item[data-mode='edit'] .btn--cancel,
.post__item[data-mode='edit'] .btn--save {
    display: flex;
}

.post__item[data-mode='edit'] .btn--edit {
    display: none;
}

.post__item .wrap {
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: start;
}

.post__item .btn__wrap {
    display: flex;
}

.post__item .btn__wrap .btn--edit {
    background: orange;
}

.post__item .btn__wrap .btn--save {
    background: #58d25e;
}

.post__item .btn__wrap .btn--cancel {
    background: red;
}

.post__item .btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 12px;
    color: white;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.edit {
    display: flex;
    width: 90px;
}

.edit input {
    border: none;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    color: red;
}

.edit input.active {
    border: 3px solid #eee;
}

.input--item,
.input--span {
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.input--item {
    border: none;
    min-width: 10px;
}

.input--span {
    display: none;
    white-space: pre;
}

.button.focus {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post__item" data-mode='none'>
  <div class="btn__wrap">
    <a class="btn btn--save " href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn--edit " href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn--cancel" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <span class="input--span"></span>
      <input class="input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="312" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <span class="input--span"></span>
      <input class="input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="55" />
    </div>
    <div class="subwrap">
      Option:
      <div class="edit">
        <input class="input--item option" type="radio" name="radio" />
        <input class="input--item option" type="radio" name="radio" />
        <input class="input--item option" type="radio" name="radio" checked />
      </div>
      Button:
      <div class="edit">
        <button class="button">Button 1</button>
        <button class="button focus">Button 2</button>
        <button class="button">Button 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post__item" data-mode='none'>
  <div class="btn__wrap">
    <a class="btn btn--save " href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn--edit " href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn--cancel" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <span class="input--span"></span>
      <input class="input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="40" maxlength="3" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <span class="input--span"></span>
      <input class="input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="79" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
    Option:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item option" type="checkbox" name="radio1" />
      <input class="input--item option" type="checkbox" name="radio1" checked />
      <input class="input--item option" type="checkbox" name="radio1" checked />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the snippet code I can't select any of the radio's or checkboxes. I tried adding name="" but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: The snippet is working fine in Chrome and FF. I am not about the problem you are facing.

Comment: I found the solution. The inputs weren't clickable until wrapped with `<label>`

Comment: Its not necessary for inputs to be wrapped with `<label>` for them to be clickable. In face label might cause the click event to trigger twice.